# Change chart data range using a drop down list (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I'm trying to Change chart data range using a drop down list (vba). Here is my code:

```
Sub SelectTable()

With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "Drop Down 2" Then
    Worksheets("Comparison").ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.SetSourceData Source:= _
    Range(.List(.Value) & "[#All]")
    Worksheets("Comparison").ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.PlotBy = xlRows

End If

End With

End Sub
```

> Getting Run-time error: '1004'

while selecting the drop-down list.

Also, this VBA will not be based on any pivot table. It's going to make changes on a Dashboard sheet.

Yes, the chart has been created using Pivot but the drop down list is a combination of UserForm and Data Validation

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your listbox return a string of your named range

```
Sub SelectTable()

With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "Drop Down 2" Then
    Worksheets("Comparison").ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.SetSourceData Source:= _
    worksheet("sheetName??").Range(.Value & "[#All]")

    Worksheets("Comparison").ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.PlotBy = xlRows

End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eric K still getting the same even after giving the Sheetname which is "Comparison".

Comment: seem like all code are fine, I cant find anything wrong. Please check on the Named Range is accessible -> Range(.Value & "[#All]")